# Deligne's theorem on the Leray spectral sequence and weights

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, spectral-sequences, hodge-theory

**Motivation** : If $f : X \to Y$ is a smooth projective map between algebraic varieties, then there is a theorem by Deligne which says that the Leray spectral sequence degenerates at $E_2$.

The proof I know uses derived categories and Hard Lefschetz on the fibers.

However I understood there was a simpler proof using weights, as suggested in the answer a previous question of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2688068/invariant-cycle-theorem).

In the article by Durfee, "A naive guide to mixed Hodge structures", the axioms state that a morphism preserves weights if the morphism is geometric i.e induced by a map of algebraic varieties. However it doesn't seems that the differentials in the Leray spectral sequence are geometric.

**Question** : Why do the differentials in the Leray spectral sequence preserve the weights ?

Comment: Why do we even need domain specific details? AFAIK the Leray spectral sequence is  a special case of the [Grothendieck spectral sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_spectral_sequence) and that one also collapses at $E_2$.

Comment: @red_trumpet : the Grothendieck spectral sequence does not degenerates at $E_2$ in general. You can look at the Hopf fibration for a simple counter-example. This is specific to the Kähler case and is a non-trivial theorem.

Comment: You do need Hard Lefschetz, but you can find a perhaps somewhat less scary presentation on pp. 467-8 of Griffiths/Harris. (I can't help with your weights question, though.)

Comment: @TedShifrin : Thanks for your comment, but I'm only interested by the proof using the weights. I'll edit my question to reflect this.